# How do I access the name of a given variable in python?

Tags: python, object

I am programming in python and need to access the name I have given to an object so as to be able to pass this as a string (concatenated with another string).

The reason I need to do this is that the program I am using forces me to create a global (which in my case is a dictionary) and I am writing a function to work in general with several different objects (which each have similar sets of properties, eg. object 1 is of length 2 (signifying in my case 2 neurons) labelled 0 and 1 and each of these has 4 properties a,b,c,d. I want to create a "dictionary filetree" of these properties but both object1 and object 2 are 2 instances of the same class, therefore I need to change the first level keys to being 'NAME1_0, 'NAME1_1', 'NAME2_0', 'NAME2_1').

```
def Init(neuron,input):
#Initialises the neuron group, arguements are neuron (neurongroup) and input (neurongroup)
global dict
dict={}
for x in range(0,len(neuron)):
    neuron[x].L=0
    neuron[x].G=0
    neuron[x].ron=1/period
    neuron[x].roff=1/period
    dict[x]={'tau_on':0.5,
             'Non_off':neuron[x].roff*0.5,
             'Non_off':neuron[x].ron*0.5,
             'Ni_on':ones(len(input))*qon*0.5,
             'Ni':ones(len(input))*qoff*0.5+ones(len(input))*qon*0.5,
             'p_current':0,
             'p_previous':0,
             'my_tau_on':[],
             'my_Non_off':[],
             'my_Noff_on':[],
             'my_Ni_on':[],
             'my_Ni':[],
             'my_p_on':[],
             'my_ron':[],
             'my_roff':[],
             'my_theta':[],
             'my_weights':[],
             'my_record_times':[]}
     dict['%s' % x, neuron]=dict.pop(x)
```

does not work as it does not give the name assigned to the object but merely the name of the object itself. for a more minimal case of my problem

```
NAME1=4
def func(x):    #creates string of 'NAME1'
    print 'x'

func(NAME1)
#output='NAME1'
```

Comment: "There must be a better way". Bear in mind that in `func(NAME1)` the expression `NAME1` is *evaluated* first and then *resulting value* is passed to the `func` function where it is assigned to the `x` parameter.

Comment: dict is a keyword.  When you use it as a name it overrides the properties of the dict object

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add a `.name` attribute to the Neuron class? BTW, Pythonistas frown upon this `range(len(...))` construct; just iterate over the sequence directly. If you really, really need indices (you almost always don't), that's what `enumerate` is for.

Comment: I think the best way for me is to add a .name attribute to the class, I was looking for a way to access the name of NAME! before it was evaluated (as pst said) but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that, the reason for the range len() is that __len__() is a method on the class that enumerates the objects (neurons in this case) within the instantiation of the class, which cannot itself be iterated over. I'd like to thank Raymond for his nice and concise explanation on a reverse globals lookup. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your could do a reverse lookup of the names in globals():

```
>>> NAME1 = 4
>>> def name_of(value):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if v is value:
                return k
        raise KeyError('did not find a name for %s' % value)

>>> name_of(NAME1)
'NAME1'
```

If the same object has been assigned to more than one name, only one name will be returned.

If you want to search more broadly than just globals, look for the dicts in `gc.get_referrers(value)` and capture all matches:

```
>>> def names_of(value):
        'Find all names for the value'
        result = []
        for d in gc.get_referrers(value):
            if isinstance(d, dict):
                for k, v in d.items():
                    if v is value:
                        result.append(k)
        return result

>>> import math
>>> pie = math.pi
>>> names_of(pie)
['pie', '_pi', 'pi', 'pi']
```

Comment: This is so awesomely evil, it makes me want to laugh, cry and cheer all at once.

Comment: You should call `gc.collect()` before `gc.get_referrers` to avoid potential "extras". From the docs: "Note that objects which have already been dereferenced, but which live in cycles and have not yet been collected by the garbage collector can be listed among the resulting referrers. To get only currently live objects, call collect() before calling get_referrers()."